# Setting an element to fade its surroundings

Tags: jquery, html, css, fade

I am trying to make an element fade its surroundings.Imagine the gray box is over the text. i would like the text that is surrounding the gray box have a fade affect.

So pretty much Fade the text around the box

Hope im making sense. Thanks for all your help!

HTML

```
 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Deseruntconsequatur nisi nulla odio eligendi sapiente rerum totam commodi          
    quae illo voluptatum soluta aut exercitationem debitis dicta ivermolestia
 </p>

 <div class="box"></div>
```

CSS

```
p {
   width: 250px;
  }

div.box {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: gray;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
}
```

JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/26t9mL47/

Comment: so you want to fade out the square in you fiddle? or what?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want. Do you want to fade in the text that's beneath the box? Or the text that's *around* the box but not the one behind it?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Fade the text around the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `box-shadow` on the box, set to the page background color to give the illusion that the text is fading out:

https://jsfiddle.net/26t9mL47/2/

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what im looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the @keyframes property in CSS:

```css
p {
   width: 250px;
  }

div.box {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: gray;
   float:left;
   margin:10px;
}

/* Animation */

@keyframes example {
   from {color: black;}
   to {color: white;}
}


p {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Deseruntconsequatur nisi nulla odio eligendi sapiente rerum totam commodi          
    quae illo voluptatum soluta aut exercitationem debitis dicta ivermolestia
</p>
```

Comment: From running the snippet, I'm not sure this works as you intended,  I see Lorem ipsum text with a small gray rectangle on top of it.

Comment: Now it's showing a box with text wrapping around it.

Comment: Yeah, i had a hard time interpreting his question, as you can see given his accepted answer lol.

Comment: I'm *still* not sure what he was asking.